# Is the documentation center broken?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, documentation

I just installed version 11.3. I opened the documentation center at 200% zoom, and it's now a total mess (and I can't click on anything):

[image: mess]

I guess zooming/scrolling is broken? I assume this is a bug?

**Update:**

It was suggested below that this would fix the issue:

```
Needs["PacletManager`"]
PacletInstall["SystemDocsUpdate1"]
```

Unfortunately, now when the zoom is set to over 100%, it looks alright and I can scroll right, but I can't scroll all the way to the left:

[image: still a mess]

I'm shocked that WRI beta testers/QA people missed this.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior on Win 10 (64 Bit). But I grant you, that zooming behavior is rather strange, e.g. the gaps increase while the font size stays the same.

Comment: On macOS 10.13.3 zoom does not work, vertical scroll works but there is no horizontal scroll bar. Magnification adjustment works to see full page width.

Comment: I have installed 11.3 both on home computer and on the one in bureau, both operate with Win7. In bureau I always get Mathematica crashed as soon as I open Documentation Center. It is not the case at home. The Clean Start did not help.

Comment: @rcollyer Just checked and it happens on both latest Windows 10 and MacOS l0.13.3

Comment: I have MMA 11.3 and macOS 10.13.3, and it works at 200%

Comment: @user5601 You are correct, this is broken for me as well

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch please contact support with as much info about the crash as you can.

Comment: Under macOS 10.13.3, I can zoom the 11.3 Documentation Center home page and various other pages up to 125%, 150%, 200%, 300% and down to 75%. Only at 50% are ends of the home page's big buttons cut off. This is on 27" iMac with default resolution 5120 x 2880.

Comment: May be related or helpful (see 3rd answer): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167887/help-example-blank-in-11-3-under-ref-exclusionsstyle/167907#167907l:

Comment: @rcollyer I already contacted it since 5 days. Its reaction is slow and yet not helpful.

Answer (score 11):

There is a known issue with the landing page when magnification is set to something other than 100%.  We are working on paclet updating the landing page to fix this, so it should be hopefully fixed automagically in the not too distant future.  Individual pages should be OK if you just type into the search bar.

Answer (score 7):

This issue should now be fixed automatically for users within 3 days. If you want to get the fix immediately, run

```
Needs["PacletManager`"]
PacletInstall["SystemDocsUpdate1"]
```

Comment: This doesn't work entirely, see my update to the question.